# Partial differentiability on a piecewise function

Tags: calculus

Given $M=\{(x,x)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : x\neq 0\}$ and the function

$$f(x,y)=   \left\{\begin{matrix}
 e^x+1\;\;\;  \forall  (x,y)\in M \\ 
 0\;\;\;  \forall  (x,y)\notin  M.
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Prove that: $f$ is partially differentiable iff $(x,y)\notin M$.

Question: Supposing that the function is partially differentiable in $M$ as operations of partially differentiable functions (I differentiate with respect to $x$, as I’ve seen in many other exercises, without going by definition with the limit to see if $f$ is partially differentiable..., so I have this:) $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,x)=e^x$. But when I try going by the definition

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,x)= \lim\frac{f(x+h,x)-f(x,x)}{h} = \lim   \frac{(1-e^x)}{h},$$

where $h \to 0$, and that limit doesn’t exist. So the first way must be wrong. But why? (I’ve seen exercises where a piecewise $f$ has a more complicated type and $f$ is partially differentiated with respect to a variable without the need checking the limit, it's like assuming from the start that in a set $f$ is partially differentiable. Why doesn’t it work here?)

Answer (score 1):

Your idea that "The function is partially differentiable in M as operations of partially differentiable functions" is incorrect.  You need to have an open interval in which the function is constructed from "partially differential functions" in order to use that and that that is not true here.

Your second calculation, that the partial derivatives do not exist, is correct.
Taking point $(x_0, x_0)$ in M, $f(x_0, x_0)= e^{x_0}+ 1$ while, for any positive h, $f(x_0+ h, x_)= 0$.  The partial derivative with respect to x would be given by $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+h, x_0)- f(x_0,x_0)}{h}= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{x_0+ h}+1- 0}{h}$ which, as you say, does not exist.

Of course, the same argument applies to the partial derivative with respect to y.

This function is differentiable for off M (and the derivatives are 0) and is not differentiable on M.